# How do I change $network?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a link to 4 different arrays but I don't know how to do it. It currently is set up like this:

```
foreach ($this->buttons as $network => $options) {
        if ($this->options['show'][$network]) {
            /*** Apply Shortcodes */
            $shortcodes = array(
                '[site_name]',
                '[permalink]',
                '[post_title]',
                '[post_image_url]',
                '[title_encode]'
                );
            $shortcode_values = array(
                $site_name,
                $permalink,
                $post_title,
                $post_image_url,
                $title_encode
                );
            $widget = str_replace($shortcodes,$shortcode_values,$options['widget']);

            $to_return .= '
        <div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_' . $network . '">
            <a href="#" class="icon icon-' . $network . '"><span>' . $options['name'] . '</span></a>
            <div class="spyr_sb_inner">' . $widget . '</div>
            </div>';
            }
        }
```

But instead of applying this:

```
<div class="spyr_sliding_share_button spyr_sb_' . $network . '">
            <a href="#" class="icon icon-' . $network . '"><span>' . $options['name'] . '</span></a>
            <div class="spyr_sb_inner">' . $widget . '</div>
            </div>';
```

To all 4 arrays I want to have a different setting for each one. The 4 arrays are all social media icons and I'm trying to change for example the facebook icon from this `<a href="#"` to this `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://boasish.com/data-url=%22%5Bpermalink%5D%22%20data-text=%22%5Bpost_title%5D/"`.

Comment: What about a switch on $network and different behaviours ? Or just put the parts you want to change in additional variables that you set in the switch.

Comment: @personne3000 That sounds like what I am looking to do. How do I do that??

Comment: I can't be much more explicit without writing your code; have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php